# Angular page alike script

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im looking for a Angular page script, that could do something like this on the drawing.

[image]

I need a goto page button and prev/next buttons. 
The page should contain a page starting with a div tag and contain normal html and angular tags.

I have tried out some Carousels, but they are not build for this purpose.
Anyone with a good link og code exampel?

Im using Bootstrap, HTML5 and AngularJS, and I want to keep it to this.

Comment: use Javascript History API for the pre/next function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Seems like [UI] Bootstrap's carousel to me - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel .

Comment: I want it on one page as a SPA. I dont want to shift between pages.. Just to shift between active div

Comment: Pavel: Im using angularstrap and it seems to conflict with ui.boorstrap. If there is a way out of that problem, then I will try that carousel

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else with a suggestion?

AngularStrap dosent support carousel, and Im using AngularStrap in other parts of my code. When I using ui.bootstrap it fails when using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min, and AngularStrap uses of different versions of ui-bootstrap-tpls.